# How to implement start and pause functions in JavaFX the correct way?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, synchronization, runnable

I'm creating a JavaFX that scans your inbox.

There are 2 buttons, one to start scanning, and one to pause scanning.

To implement this I've created a new thread passing it in a runnable where the scanInbox() function is called.

However, when I press the pause button to invoke thread.wait(), it seems to get stuck.

What would be the best way to implement this function here?

```
public class WebsiteOverviewController {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Website> deleteTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Website, String> deleteColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Website> keepTable;

    @FXML 
    private TableColumn<Website, String> keepColumn;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton scanButton;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton pauseButton;

    private BooleanProperty isScanning = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    private MainApp mainApp;

    private FilteredList<Website> keepData;

    private FilteredList<Website> deleteData;

    Task<Void> task;
    Thread thread;


    public WebsiteOverviewController() {

    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        deleteColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().websiteProperty());
        keepColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().websiteProperty());

        scanButton.visibleProperty().bind(isScanning.not());
        pauseButton.visibleProperty().bind(isScanning);
    }

    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;

        keepData = new FilteredList<>(mainApp.getWebsiteData(), p -> p.getKeep());
        deleteData = new FilteredList<>(mainApp.getWebsiteData(), p -> !p.getKeep());
        deleteTable.setItems(deleteData);
        keepTable.setItems(keepData);
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleScanInbox() {
        isScanning.set(true);


        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mainApp.handleScanInbox();
            }

        });
        thread.start();


    }

    @FXML
    public void handlePauseScanInbox() {
        isScanning.set(false);
        try {
            synchronized(thread) {
                thread.wait();
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: `thread.wait()` does not causes the instance of the `Thread` referenced by `thread` to wait, it causes the `Thread` that is currently executing that to wait, which is the JavaFX Application Thread.

Comment: gotcha. what's the best approach then? very new to concurrency here

Comment: The important part is actually in `mainApp.handleScanInbox()`. If the implementation of that "scanning" is written continuously in whole block, then there is no way to stop (pause) it from outside. You have to do the "scanning" in small batches, and check for a particular `volatile boolean` flag to see if it is paused. If it is paused you can find an object to call `.wait()` on to temporarily halt the thread, then call `notify()` on the same object to resume. You need to read more on this topic before you continue writing this.

Comment: it's basically a for loop that loops through ur entire inbox so i guess that constitutes as a continuously whole block. how would i design it to do scanning in small batches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex's solution is working fine, but if you still want to use a lower-level of threading management (wait-notify), this is how you can do it:

```
public class WebsiteOverviewController {
    @FXML
    public void handleScanInbox() {
        isScanning.set(true);

        thread = new Thread(mainApp::handleScanInbox);
        thread.start();
    }

    @FXML
    public void handlePauseScanInbox() {
        isScanning.set(false);
        mainApp.pause();
    }

    // Another handler for resuming...
}

public class MainApp {
    private final AtomicBoolean paused = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public void handleScanInbox() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) { // This could be a while loop
            synchronized (paused) {
                while (paused.get()) { // Using while so that it could re-wait in the case that the object was falsely notified
                    try {
                        pause.wait();
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Do whatever you need to do
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        pause.compareAndSet(false, true);
    }

    public void resume() {
        synchronized (paused) {
            if (paused.get()) {
                paused.set(false);
                paused.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Update

If you want to be able to call a particular to toggle between pausing and resuming, you can add another method for this:

```
// In MainApp
public void togglePauseResume() {
    synchronized (paused) {
        if (paused.get()) {
            paused.set(false);
            paused.notify();
        }
        else {
            paused.set(true); // You don't need compareAndSet() because paused object has been used for synchronization (i.e. locked)
        }
    }
}
```

In any case, you should try to avoid this:

```
@FXML
public void handleButton() {
    if (mainApp.isPaused()) { // You added a getter for paused
        mainApp.pause();
    }
    else {
        mainApp.resume();
    }
}
```

This is because `MainApp.paused` can potentially change in between the getter and `pause()` (i.e. race condition).

### Update 2

If you just want to use a single method to start/resume the thread, you could simply create the thread if it is `null`, or call `resume()` otherwise.

```
@FXML
public void handleScanInbox() {
    isScanning.set(true); // Not sure if you still need this

    if (thread == null) {
        thread = new Thread(mainApp::handleScanInbox);
        thread.start();
    }
    else if (thread.isAlive()) {
        mainApp.resume();
    }
}
```

I have also changed `if (paused.get())` to `while (paused.get())`, in case `notify()` was called on `paused` by accident.

Comment: Excellent thank u ! Just a quick last question - if I wanted a scan button to implement both `handleScanInbox` and `resume`, what would be the best way to to implement it? Would it better to check the state of the thread?

Comment: @doctopus Updated.

Comment: oh actually i meant having the start and resume functions as one

Comment: @doctopus Updated again. Also, there wasn't a problem with Alex's solution, it was my mistake. Difference-wise, Alex's solution is much easier to implement, but there may be some delay due to the loop-sleeping. His approach is similar to taking a nap and setting an alarm clock that repeatedly rings now and then, then checking if there is any work to do; this approach is similar to having a colleague to tell you when a work has arrived, so you could nap till then.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it using AtomicBoolean, set it`s true when paused, and check it inside your mainApp.handleScanInbox() method.
You can check if it paused every iteration, every 10 iterations, or every run of the method, depending on your requirements

```
    AtomicBoolean paused = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    @FXML
    public void handlePauseScanInbox() {
        paused.compareAndSet(false,true);
    }

    //mainApp.handleScanInbox();
    public void handleScanInbox(AtomicBoolean paused){
        for(/* your entire inbox*/){
            while(paused.get()){
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should not call paused.set(false) after the while loop, it is not the business of this method and anuway it would` not go after while loop before it changed to false previously. Volatile boolean quite dangerous compared to atomic, as it is easy to do non-atomic operations on them. For example compare and set for volatile boolean not atomic, and may change between check and set.

Comment: Oh, my bad... I was aware of the differences between `AtomicBoolean` and `volatile boolean`, but it seems like I totally confused myself, somehow. Thanks for replying so I could re-read it again.